# Libgit2sharp:how to use "git pull“

Tags: git-pull, libgit2sharp

```
using (var repo = new Repository("path/to/your/repo"))
{
    LibGit2Sharp.PullOptions options = new LibGit2Sharp.PullOptions();
    options.FetchOptions = new FetchOptions();
    options.FetchOptions.CredentialsProvider = new CredentialsHandler(
        (url, usernameFromUrl, types) =>
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials()
            {
                Username = USERNAME,
                Password = PASSWORD
            });
    repo.Network.Pull(new LibGit2Sharp.Signature(USERNAME, EMAIL, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now)), options)
}
```

i do not konw how to set arguments,when i use it,one error will show-----Unsupported URL protocol.could you tell me how to set arguments?

Comment: What is the URL protocol that you're trying to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the url you are using.

For instance, [issue 649](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/649) clearly states:

> `git.git` supports relative URLs in remote configurations and resolves them relative to the working directory.
>   `libgit2` currently fails with "Unsupported URL protocol".
>
> It expects paths to be absolute.

So if your url is actually a local path, make sure it is an absolute path (and not a relative one).

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36100618/libgit2sharphow-to-use-git-pull/36119149#comment60018454_36119149) by [崔重阳](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6077300/%E5%B4%94%E9%87%8D%E9%98%B3), using an https instea of an sssh url is supported.

Comment: ok! thank you!  i  find the reason.i used ssh before,if i change http,it is successful!

Comment: @崔重阳 OK. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.